# Создание представления SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, view

Я пытаюсь создать представление sql, условие которого приведено ниже. Буду рад любым подсказкам.

Человек на протяжении жизни может быть владельцем нескольких паспортов. Паспорта могут меняться в связи с истечением их срока действия, утратой и так далее. Необходимо составить структуру БД из одной таблицы, где будут храниться следующие данные:

- Фамилия
- Имя (ID отсутствует, однофамильцы (имя и фамилия) считаются одним и тем же человеком)
- Серия паспорта
- Номер паспорта.

Создайте представление данных (View), не Stored Procedure, при помощи которого возможно получить данные всех паспортов человека, указав только серию и номер одного паспорта.

Пример применения:

```
SELECT *
FROM PassportView
WHERE passportSeria =‘AA‘ AND  passpotNumber=‘12345678‘
```

Comment: Обычный self-JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW ViewAllPassports AS
SELECT DISTINCT
        PV1."Имя"
        ,PV1."Фамилия"
        ,PV2."Серия паспорта"
        ,PV2."Номер паспорта"
FROM PassportView AS PV1
JOIN PassportView AS PV2 ON PV1."Имя" = PV2."Имя"
    AND PV1."Фамилия" = PV2."Фамилия"
```

Проверка скрипта:

```
;WITH PassportView AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
    VALUES 
        (N'Сивова', N'Татьяна', 5007, 123456),
        (N'Сивова', N'Татьяна', 5008, 654321),
        (N'Горкунова', N'Ксения', 5009, 654321),
        (N'Митрофанов', N'Вячеслав', 5010, 654321),
        (N'Косова', N'Анастасия', 5011, 654321)
    ) AS PassportView([Фамилия], [Имя], [Серия паспорта], [Номер паспорта])
)
SELECT DISTINCT
        PV1."Имя"
        ,PV1."Фамилия"
        ,PV2."Серия паспорта"
        ,PV2."Номер паспорта"
FROM PassportView AS PV1
JOIN PassportView AS PV2 ON PV1."Имя" = PV2."Имя"
    AND PV1."Фамилия" = PV2."Фамилия"
```

Comment: При distinct выводит только одну запись, если убрать, то выдаёт нужно количество записей, однако во всех строках одинаковые значения.

Comment: @Crazy_BOO добавил проверку, всё работает. Проверь свою базу, может там 1 человек несколько раз записан